# Need to extract the phone number within the string

Tags: php, regex, preg-match

I have a string like the following which can change every time.

> style="margin: 0;">\r\n
>   Phone\r\n </p>\r\n  <p style="font-weight: bold; margin:
>   0;">\r\n      0411313062\r\n      </p>\r\n
>   </td>\r\n
>   </tr>\r\n
>   <tr>\r\n
>   <td style="padding-bottom: 18px;">\r\n

I need to extract the phone number 0411313062 out of this string.

Comment: `which can change every time` ... in order to use regex effectively, you would need some known structure.  But I think you should just use an XML/HTML parser instead.

Comment: `strip_tags` ignore `\r\n` and whitespace and pull the numbers until the end of the line?

Comment: e.g. `preg_match('/^Phone[\\\r\\\n\h]+?(\d+)/m', strip_tags($string), $match);`? If the format changes everytime you can't regex, I assume you meant the number change everytime..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try this:

```
$text = 'style="margin: 0;">\r\n
Phone\r\n </p>\r\n <p style="font-weight: bold; margin: 0;">\r\n 0411313062\r\n </p>\r\n
</td>\r\n
</tr>\r\n
<tr>\r\n
<td style="padding-bottom: 18px;">\r\n';
preg_match("/[0-9]{10}/", $text, $matches);// in case of multiple occurrences us preg_match_all
print_r($matches[0]);//0411313062
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
preg_match('\(?([0-9]{3})\s*\)?\s*-?\s*([0-9]{3})\s*-?\s*([0-9]{4})', $string, $match );
```

See it in action,

https://regex101.com/r/pLqDWw/3

This will match 7 or 10  digit phone numbers with or without the `-` or `(area code)` such as `800-555-5555` or `8005555555` or `(800)555-5555` or `555-5555` etc

If you have to match more then one number, I would suggest using something like PHPQuery, to refine the text ( html ) you are searching for it against.  You could try something simpler like, `preg_match_all` but once you get the hang of PHPQuery you'll thank me.

Answer (score 0):

this code works fine. Try this

```
$tab = <<<EOD
style="margin: 0;">\r\n Phone\r\n </p>\r\n <p style="font-weight: bold;   margin: 0;">\r\n 0411313062\r\n </p>\r\n </td>\r\n
 </tr>\r\n
 <tr>\r\n
<td style="padding-bottom: 18px;">\r\n) EOD;


$input= explode("\r\n", $tab);
print_r($input);
```

the phone number is

```
echo $input[4];
```